# Javascript Injection error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube, code-injection, ads

I wrote a javascript that removes youtube ads by replacing the embedded video with a link that youtube provides so that you may embed the video on your own site. However, it gives two different results: the first result is when I use a javascript injection it fails, the second is when I execute the script through inspect element.

Here is the code, use it to see the result of both:

```
javascript:var url=document.getElementsByTagName("link")[document.getElementsByTagName("link").length-1].href; 
var x=document.getElementById("player-api");
var iFrame="<iframe width="+getComputedStyle(x).width+" height="+getComputedStyle(x).height+" src="+url+"  frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
try{document.getElementById("player-api").innerHTML=iFrame} catch (Exception){};
try{document.getElementById("player-api-legacy").innerHTML=iFrame} catch (Exception) {};
```

Ps. this is in Chrome, it works perfectly in Safari (injection and inspect element)